# How to delete selected rows from a listview populated from SQLite db

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I use the following code to get a list of selected items from a listview (populated from an SQLite database). Everything is fine with the dialog successfully showing the list.

```
    private String getCheckedItems() {

           SparseBooleanArray positions = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

           for (int i = (positions.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {

                    Cursor cursor = (Cursor)  getListView().getItemAtPosition(positions.keyAt(i));                  
                    if(positions.valueAt(i) == true)                     
                        sb.append(Utility.decodeContent("- " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("word")) + "\n"));                
                }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                FavBawords2.this);

        builder.setTitle((getResources().getString(R.string.HisFav_del_one)));
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.clear);
        builder.setMessage(sb);

        builder.setPositiveButton((R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                onPositiveButtonClicked();
            }
        }); 

        builder.setNegativeButton((R.string.cancel_action), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //do something else
            }
        }); 

        builder.show(); 

        return null;
                 }
```

I want to select one or more items to delete from the listview and database. Here is the code to delete the selected items:

```
    protected void onPositiveButtonClicked() {          

        SparseBooleanArray positions = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();

        for(int i = 0; i < getListView().getCount(); i++){
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor)  getListView().getItemAtPosition(positions.keyAt(i)); 
            String str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("word"));
            if(positions.valueAt(i) == true) {

                if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {  
                    //favitems is my table                  
                    db.execSQL("delete from favitems WHERE word ='"+str+"'");   

                   }                
            }

           }            
        }
```

Sadly, I get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error as below although the selected items are actually deleted.

```
  06-08 18:01:19.587: W/dalvikvm(18952): threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
  06-08 18:01:19.588: W/System.err(18952): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
  06-08 18:01:19.589: W/System.err(18952):  at android.util.SparseBooleanArray.keyAt(SparseBooleanArray.java:176)
  06-08 18:01:19.589: W/System.err(18952):  at the_app.activity.FavBawords2$ModeCallback.onPositiveButtonClicked(FavBawords2.java:881)
  06-08 18:01:19.589: W/System.err(18952):  at the_app.activity.FavBawords2$ModeCallback$1.onClick(FavBawords2.java:844)
  06-08 18:01:19.589: W/System.err(18952):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
  06-08 18:01:19.589: W/System.err(18952):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
  06-08 18:01:19.589: W/System.err(18952):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
  06-08 18:01:19.589: W/System.err(18952):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
  06-08 18:01:19.589: W/System.err(18952):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  06-08 18:01:19.589: W/System.err(18952):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  06-08 18:01:19.589: W/System.err(18952):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
  06-08 18:01:19.590: W/System.err(18952):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
  06-08 18:01:19.590: W/System.err(18952):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  06-08 18:01:19.590: W/dalvikvm(18952): threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
  06-08 18:01:19.591: E/AndroidRuntime(18952): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

I guess the problem may lie in this line:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < getListView().getCount(); i++)
```

because when I change it into

```
 for (int i = (positions.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--)
```

I don't have the problem anymore. But the deletion fails.
I wonder if you can do a little help to explain why I have such a problem and show me a way out.

Help highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your positions.keyAt(i)? You cannot use directly Cursor cursor = (Cursor)  getListView().getItemAtPosition(i); ?

Comment: It's `CheckedItemPositions`, but why not, please?

Answer (score 1):

You are right problem is at this line only. 
`for(int i = 0; i < getListView().getCount(); i++)`

**Why :** Because you are using total items size of ListView, while you may have selected only few of them. This is reason for `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Write query like this

```
delete from favitems WHERE word like '"+str+"'"
```

Comment: You mean I should use `for(int i = 0; i < getListView().getCount(); i++)` and `delete from favitems WHERE word like '"+str+"'"`? I've just change to those but the problem persists.

Comment: I mean use `for (int i = (positions.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--)`  and what error you are getting

Comment: No error, but it seems the deletion doesn't work. No item is deleted from the listview and db.

Comment: log and check what exactly your query is `delete from favitems WHERE word like '"+str+"'"`